# Vue Js - Transition only when component is visible

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm doing some transitions using the transition tag and they're working perfectly. The problem is that transitions happen even if the component is not visible, I wanted it to happen only when the user arrived on that part of the page. Is there any way to do this with Vue?

HTML:

```
    <transition name="products" appear>
        <h2 class="container">Products</h2>
    </transition>
```

CSS:

```
    @keyframes slide-in {
        from { transform: translateX(-60px); }
        to { transform: translateX(0); }
    }

    .products-enter-active {
        animation: slide-in 2s ease;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to transition the element in when it's visible in the viewport, look at intersection observer and conditionally render it using `v-if`. VueJS transition does not check if the element is in the viewport or not: that kind of logic has to be implemented by yourself.

Comment: Maybe you should listen the scroll event and render the element when it's in the viewport.